# use mock in python to return instead of raising exception?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

This is what I plan to do:

```
def foo(flag):
    """
    other irrelevant code
    """
    if flag:
        import random
        return random.random()
    """
    other irrelevant code
    """
    raise Exception()
```

I know `mock` can be used to change the behavior of class or function, but not sure how it can be used to return instead of raising exception.

I am wondering if there is any way `mock` can change this `raise` into return something, without affecting the other code

Comment: Have you tried using the following decorator: `@mock.patch('path.to.foo', return_value=whatever_you_want)`?

Comment: Probably cannot. I have another `return` in some branch. Let me change the description :)

Answer (score 0):

I find the `wraps` argument helpful for this sort of situation.  Here I create a generic function `capture` that will pass through any return value but will turn exceptions into a return value.  Then I use `mock.patch` with the `wraps` argument.
I use `functools.partial` to let the `capture` function know what we're wrapping.
Untested, but this should give the basic idea.

```
def capture(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    try: return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception: return whatever_you_like

importe module, functools
with mock.patch('module.foo', wraps = functools.partial(capture, module.foo)):
    do stuff
```